# OperationalError connection is bad: Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: python, postgresql, database-connection, psycopg2

I'm running a script that polls the db continuously checking for new rows that need to be processed. This script is running as a background process in a docker container which runs the flask app in the foreground(main command/process in the dockerfile).

The service seems to work perfectly fine under less load, But when the load is increased, meaning when ~ 1000 to 2000 new rows are added to the table(via post endpoint in the flask app - one API call added one row), the following error occurs in the background script:

```
ERROR:root:connection is bad: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/MyService/relay_event.py", line 52, in main
    with psycopg.connect(conninfo=connection_info, autocommit=True, row_factory=dict_row) as conn:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 728, in connect
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
psycopg.OperationalError: connection is bad: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection is bad: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Now, this error keeps happening for some time and automatically it starts working after a few minutes, and this burst pattern keeps occurring. Reading the error message from the stack trace, I felt the db was down, but that is not the case. I also tried querying the DB exactly when this error is happening in the script, and I was able to get the results for my query. I'm unable to understand what is making my script not connect with the DB, when the DB server is actually up and working fine.

The script(relay_event.py) looks something like this:

```py
 while True:
     try:
        with psycopg.connect(conninfo=connection_info, autocommit=True, row_factory=dict_row) as conn:

            cur = conn.cursor()

            with conn.transaction():
                # getting rows to be processed
                cur.execute(
                        '''
                        SELECT * FROM request_store
                        WHERE
                        (transaction_status='awaiting')
                        or
                        (
                            transaction_status='completed'
                            and
                            "status" = 'failure'
                            and
                            retry_count < %s
                            and
                            last_updated_time < (now() at time zone 'utc' - INTERVAL '%s minutes')
                        )
                        ORDER BY created_time ASC FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED LIMIT %s;
                        ''',
                        (
                            config.get("min_retries", 3),
                            config.get("retry_after_mins", 10),
                            config.get("limit_rows", 1)
                        )
                )
                rows = cur.fetchall()

                if len(rows) == 0:
                    print("No new rows found")
                else:
                    # processing the transaction
                    for row in rows:
                        # pushing data to a queue
                        push_info = process_data.push_data(row)

                        # updating the row to `pending` stage
                        cur.execute(
                                '''
                                UPDATE request_store 
                                SET last_updated_time = NOW(), transaction_status='pending', retry_count=%s, response=%s
                                WHERE transaction_id = %s;
                                ''',
                                (
                                    row["retry_count"] + 1,
                                    json.dumps(
                                        {
                                            "response": "success",
                                            "push_info": push_info,
                                            "host_details": get_host_data()
                                        }
                                    ),
                                    row["transaction_id"]
                                )
                        )

            cur.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        # log info
    finally:
        sleep(0.5)
```

**Db configs changes:**

1. max_connections from 5000 to 9000
2. superuser_reserved_connections from 64 to 128
3. shared_buffers from 512MB to 2GB
4. work_mem from 512kB to 4MB

**Code changes:**

I tried reducing the number of connections by removing connection pooling in all the services so that every time a connection is created, it's closed after use.

**Result:**

After making these changes, it's still reproducible, but with a slightly higher load than earlier.

I'm new to SQL/PostgreSQL and i'm finding it hard to debug and fix this issue. Any help or suggestions to fix this issue are highly appreciated.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem: *Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?*. It is either: a) Server not actually running. b) Running but not listening on the `port` or `address` supplied in the `connection_info`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, but there is no issue with `connection_info`. As i explained everything works initially, but when the load is increased this error is happening.

Comment: Alright. 1) Have you tailed  the Postgres log to see if it provides more information? 2) Is the Postgres server running in the same container as the Flask app or somewhere else?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - [1]yeah, no errors logged. [2] Its running in a different VM.

Another thing that I noticed is, The DB is reachable from from all the other vm's but for the one where My app is running.

Comment: I'm confused, earlier you said it is reachable but fails under a load now you say it is not reachable. My guess is there is some sort of 'network' issue between the VM in question and the VM with the database. You will need to  provide more information on how communication is done between the VM's.